PostgreSQL causing ISSUES
I am adding a constraint using DRIZZLE ORM and supabase using the following code snippet:
ALTER TABLE profiles
ADD CONSTRAINT profiles_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES auth.users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.validate_username_before_change()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER SET search_path = ''
    AS $$
    BEGIN 

-- CHECK IF IT'S AN INSERT OPERATION
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
-- ENSURE USERNAME IS PRESENT
IF NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'username' IS NULL OR NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'username' = '' THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Username must be provided when creating a new user!';
END IF;
END IF;

-- CHECK for Username uniqueness (for both insert and update)
IF EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM public.profiles
WHERE username = NEW.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'username'
AND id != NEW.id -- Exclude the current user when updating
) THEN  
RAISE EXCEPTION 'User with username % already exists!', username = NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'username';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER check_username_before_update_auth_users
BEFORE UPDATE ON auth.users
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.raw_user_meta_data->>'username' IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'username')
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.validate_username_before_change();
CREATE TRIGGER check_username_before_insert_auth_users
BEFORE INSERT ON auth.users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.validate_username_before_change();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_profile_username()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER SET search_path = ''
AS $$
BEGIN
UPDATE public.profiles
SET username = NEW.raw_user_meta_data-\>\>'username'
WHERE id = NEW.id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER on_auth_user_updated
AFTER UPDATE ON auth.users
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.raw_user_meta_data->>'username' IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'username')
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.update_profile_username();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER SET search_path = ''
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.profiles(id, username)
VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'username')
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER on_auth_user_created
AFTER INSERT ON auth.users
FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user();

I have re-watched and re-verified that the code should work but can't seem to find a proper validator online because when I run the migration
I just get a syntax error BEFORE OR AFTER RETURN and all the blocks are ended from what I can tell

You can’t use a trigger function for uniqueness because of concurrency and transaction visibility. Use a unique constraint.
